# Why Mathematica can't solve this? NSolve or Solve

Tags: equation-solving

***I want solution of x and y which should be positive real numbers***

```
Solve[2*(1 - a)*((x)^-n) + 2*a*((y)^-n) - 1 == 
   0 && (1 - a)*((x)^(1 - n)) + a*((y)^(1 - n)) - 1 == 0 , {x, y}]
```

> During evaluation of In[2]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being
>   used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for
>   complete solution information. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[2]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give
>   solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
>
> Out[2]= {{y -> 2^(1/n) ((a x^n)/(-2 + 2 a + x^n))^(1/n)}}

****Supppose now I plug in certain numeric values n=0.3 a=0.6, it still can't solve it .***

```
NSolve[2*(1 - 0.6)*((x)^-0.3) + 2*0.6*((y)^-0.3) - 1 == 
   0 && (1 - 0.6)*((x)^(1 - 0.3)) + 0.6*((y)^(1 - 0.3)) - 1 == 0, {x, 
  y}, Reals]
```

> NSolve::ratnz: NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact
>   coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
>   system and numericizing the result. >>

Comment: Sorry can you please tell me how can you tell from the contour plot there is no real solutions? I ploted it and see two curves that are not intersecting

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica *can* solve it if you use explicit numerical values for the parameters, and it does return a result: `{}`.  From the [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) doc page:

> `NSolve` gives `{}` if there are no solutions to the equations.

From a contour plot of your equations I believe this result is correct and there are no *real valued* solutions:

```
ContourPlot[{
  -1 + 4/(5 x^(3/10)) + 6/(5 y^(3/10)) == 0, 
  -1 + (2 x^(7/10))/5 + (3 y^(7/10))/5 == 0
  },
 {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

Generally, if Mathematica can't do a symbolic computation, it'll return the input command.  If it returns something else, it has a specific meaning.

Comment: I wonder what one should make of the 'special' solution `y -> 2^(1/n) ((a x^n)/(-2 + 2 a + x^n))^(1/n)`. Any hint for which values of a and n this is a solution of the system? For `a=0.6` and `n=1/2` one can find the pairs `{1,36}` and `{4,4}` for `{x,y}` but these verify only the first equation and not the second.